# Is there any way to make for_each take references?

Tags: c++, functional-programming

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) cites for_each as follows:

```
  template<class InputIterator, class Function>
  Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);
```

I have a collection `std::list<std::string>`, and a function `void Do(std::string)` works fine when given to `for_each` along with the iterators. But if I supply a function like `void Do(std::string&)`, it does not compile. Is there a way around it? Or should I forget about it as some RVO like magic is going on? :D

EDIT:

```
bool PluginLoader::LoadSharedObjects()                              
{                                                                   
    for_each(l_FileNames.begin(), l_FileNames.end(), bind1st(mem_fun(&PluginLoader::LoadSharedObject),this));                                                                      
}   

void PluginLoader::LoadSharedObject(const std::string sFileName)   
{                                                                   
    void* pHandle = dlopen(sFileName.c_str(), i_LibMode);           
    //if(pHandle == NULL)
    //Check dlerror

    //Add handle to list
}
```

Code added. I woul like `LoadSharedObject` function to be of the form `void PluginLoader::LoadSharedObject(const std::string& sFileName)` if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not with for_each but with bind1st and mem_fun. They simply dont't support what you're trying to do. They cannot handle functions which take reference parameters. You could write **your own functor**, use **boost::bind** or wait until you're able to use C++0x lambdas.

Example for **your own functor**:

```
struct LoadSharedObjFunctor
{
    PluginLoader *pl;
public:
    explicit(PluginLoader *p)
    : pl(p) {}

    void operator()(std::string const& cref) const
    { return pl->LoadSharedObject(cref); }
};

...
std::for_each(...,...,LoadSharedObjFunctor(this));
...
```

Of course, you don't *have* to use std::for_each. A simple for-loop will do as well.

Comment: I can't use any third party libraries.:(. I don't think writing one of my own would turn up well :).

Comment: @nakiya: Then write your own functor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use boost, then what you want is `boost:::bind`.

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
...
for_each(l_FileNames.begin(),
         l_FileNames.end(),
         boost::bind(&PluginLoader::LoadSharedObject, this, _1));
```

Just for fun, here is why what you are trying doesn't work:

This `mem_fun(&PluginLoader::LoadSharedObject)` creates an object of type `mem_fun1_t<void, PluginLoader, const string &>`.

So `bind1st(mem_fun(&PluginLoader::LoadSharedObject),this)` creates an object of type `binder1st< mem_fun1_t<void, PluginLoader, const string &> >`.

The problem is that `binder1st` defines a function that looks like:
`ResultType operator()(const ArgType &)`, where `ArgType` is `const string &`.  So effectively it means you are trying to form a reference to a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The current standard isn't clear whether such usage of `for_each` should be allowed or not, and different implementations behave differently - some accept that but some not. That was considered unfortunate by some people, so C++0x is going to fix the situation by explicitly allowing mutating operations passed to `for_each` if the iterator is modifiable.

On the EDIT: const references aren't a problem. What errors do you get?

Comment: When is this illusive C++0x going to come out. I keep seeing it everywhere these days. :D

Comment: I can't wait for it myself :D I really hope it happens on March 2011. Quoting from http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#when-standard : "The new standard is likely to be called C++11, but even a minor bureacratic delay could make that C++12."

Comment: C++ is really convoluted isn't it? :D

Comment: By no means trivial for sure :D